# How to use blogger api v3 in blogger to post comment and fetch

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to post comment and fetch it

**Make this using blogger v3 api**

```html
<h1>Comment Form</h1>
<form id="comment-form">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br><br>
  <label for="comment">Comment:</label><br>
  <textarea id="comment" name="comment" required></textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/request"></script>

<script>
  extend.remove();
  cookies.remove();
  helpers.remove();
  gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: 'AIzaSyDZhYG2aZx-9XbFzJHi0H6Xjqn2Ntvbbqo',
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger'
    }).then(function(auth2) {
      if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
        console.log('User is authenticated.');
      } else {
        console.log('User is not authenticated.');
        auth2.signIn();
      }
    });
  });

  function postComment() {
    var request =
      gapi.load('client', function() {
        gapi.client.load('blogger', 'v3', function() {
          gapi.client.blogger.comments.insert({
            'blogId': blogID, //i already create variables blogid and postid
            'postId': postID,
            'isDraft': 'true',
            'body': document.getElementById('comment').value,
            'author': {
              'displayName': document.getElementById('name').value
            }
          });
        });
      });
    request.execute(function(comment) {
      console.log('Comment posted: ' + comment.id);
      document.getElementById('comment-form').reset();
      alert('Comment posted!');
    });
    return false;
  }

  document.getElementById('comment-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then(postComment);
  });
</script>
<script>
  fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/${blogID}/posts/${postID}/comments?key=AIzaSyDZhYG2aZx-9XbFzJHi0H6Xjqn2Ntvbbqo`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      let x_lts = JSON.stringify(response);
      t = JSON.parse(x_lts);
      for (let i = 0; i < t["items"].length; i++) {
        console.log(t["items"][i]["content"]);
      };
    });
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

this is a template to show what i want please craete a complete template comment system i mody all codes but i only want it to post ability
my [website](https://scienhac.blogspot.com/)

to code a dummy template that work in blogger using blogger api v3

so help me i try almost past 5 days